# Ubuntu full installation on Chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I just bought a Google Chromebook HP 14 and I am very happy to be honest.

But I do miss my Ubuntu OS :), and the options available to use aren't a real native OS system but adaptations that sometimes do not work :(

Does anyone have an idea how to install with dual boot Ubuntu alongside Chrome OS?

Comment: Oh boy, it would be pretty much be the same as resising the chrome partition on your hard drive and then installing through USB, I wouldve thought

Comment: Thanks Adam, the problem is that I dont know how to change the BIOS in order to make Chromebook "read" the USB flash drive in order to resize and install Ubuntu.
Do you have an idea?